# How to get XML data and bind in tableview in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xml, odata, alamofire

I have been using oData url with basic authorisation. oData response in XML format. I could response data from oData url using Alamofire. But i could not able to get specific value from XML.

Here is my XML response data:

```
 <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="http://hostname:portNumber/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPRJ_PM_APPS_IH_SRV/">
<id>hostname:portNumber/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPRJ_PM_APPS_IH_SRV/WorkOrder</id>
<title type="text">WorkOrderF4Set</title>
<updated>2019-08-16T15:37:48Z</updated>
<author>
    <name/>
</author>
<link href="WorkOrderF4Set" rel="self" title="WorkOrderF4Set"/>
<entry>
    <id>hostname:portNumber/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPRJ_PM_APPS_IH_SRV/WorkOrder('000000504780')</id>
    <title type="text">WorkOrder('000000504780')</title>
    <updated>2019-08-16T15:37:48Z</updated>
    <category term="ZPRJ_PM_APPS_IH_SRV.WorkOrder" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <link href="WorkOrder('000000504780')" rel="self" title="WorkOrder"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
            <d:WorkOrder>000000504780</d:WorkOrder>
            <d:Description>General Maintenance testing</d:Description>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
<entry>
    <id>http://hostname:portNumber/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPRJ_PM_APPS_IH_SRV/WorkOrder('000000821400')</id>
    <title type="text">WorkOrderF4Set('000000821400')</title>
    <updated>2019-08-16T15:37:48Z</updated>
    <category term="ZPRJ_PM_APPS_IH_SRV.WorkOrder" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <link href="WorkOrder('000000821400')" rel="self" title="WorkOrder"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
            <d:WorkOrder>000000821400</d:WorkOrder>
            <d:Description>PUMP LEAKING</d:Description>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

here i am trying get **d:WorkOrder** and **d:Description** value and bind into table view cell.

here is my code to get response from alamofire:

```
  func loadData(){



    let user = "raXXXXXX"

    let password = "xxxxxxx"

    let url = "http://hostname:portNumber/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPRJ_PM_APPS_IH_SRV/WorkOrder"



    let loginString = "\(user):\(password)"





    guard let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {

        return

    }

    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

    print("base 64 login :\(base64LoginString)")



    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64LoginString)"]


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)

        .responseString { response in

            print(" - API url: \(String(describing: response.request!))")   // original url request

            var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode



            switch response.result {

            case .success:

                print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")

                if let stringg = response.result.value {

                    print("XML: \(stringg)")



                    let data = stringg.data(using: .utf8)



                    let xml = try! XML.parse(data!)

                    print("xml value:\(xml)")



                    let element = xml.feed.entry

                    print("element xml :\(element)")



                    let results = xml["feed", "entry"]

                    print("result xml :\(results)")





                    for result in results["entry"] {

                        if let jobtitle = result["d:WorkOrder"].text {

                            print("job::\(jobtitle)")

                        }

                    }

                    if let attributeValue = xml.feed.entry[0].attributes["d:WorkOrder"] {

                        print("attributeValue\(attributeValue)") // -> 2

                    }



                    let work = "d:WorkOrder"

                    print("feed:\(xml.feed.entry[0].WorkOrder)")



                    guard let jsonData = stringg.data(using: .utf8) else {return}

                    guard let jsonResponse = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)) as? [[String:Any]] else {return}

                    let idArray = jsonResponse.flatMap{$0["d:WorkOrder"] as? String}



                    print("idarray::\(idArray)")

                }


                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

                    print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string

                }

            case .failure(let error):

                statusCode = error._code // statusCode private

                print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")

                print(error)

            }

    }


}//loaddata
```

Also tried using XMLSwiftyParser pod, but did not came up well.

```
  let data = stringg.data(using: .utf8)



                    let xml = try! XML.parse(data!)

                    print("xml value:\(xml)")



                    let element = xml.feed.entry

                    print("element xml :\(element)")



                    let results = xml["feed", "entry"]

                    print("result xml :\(results)")





                    for result in results["entry"] {

                        if let jobtitle = result["d:WorkOrder"].text {

                            print("job::\(jobtitle)")

                        }

                    }
```

How to parse d:WorkOrder and d:Description in table view.

Any help much appreciate pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse any xml data using this code. Then you can access your data in parsedData variable. Using the helper function "search", you can get any of the value of any key.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

    var parsedData = Dictionary<String,Any>()
    var openElements = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Feed", withExtension: "xml") {
            if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: path) {
                parser.delegate = self
                parser.parse()
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        openElements.append(elementName)

        parsedData[elementName] = attributeDict
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        _ = openElements.popLast()

        if let last = openElements.last, var dict = parsedData[last] as? [String:Any], let data = parsedData[elementName] {
            if let prevData = dict[elementName] {
                dict[elementName] = [prevData, data]
            } else {
                dict[elementName] = data
            }

            parsedData[last] = dict

            parsedData.removeValue(forKey: elementName)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let string = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if !string.isEmpty, let last = openElements.last, var dict = parsedData[last] as? [String:Any] {
            dict["text"] = string

            parsedData[last] = dict
        }
    }

    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        search(key: "d:WorkOrder", in: parsedData, completion: { print($0) })
        search(key: "d:Description", in: parsedData, completion: { print($0) })
    }

    func search(key:String, in dict:[String:Any], completion:((Any) -> ())) {
        if let foundValue = dict[key] {
            completion(foundValue)
        } else {
            dict.values.enumerated().forEach {
                if let innerDict = $0.element as? [String:Any] {
                    search(key: key, in: innerDict, completion: completion)
                }

                if let innerArray = $0.element as? [[String:Any]] {
                    innerArray.forEach({ innerDict in
                        search(key: key, in: innerDict, completion: completion)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works fine how to use in tableview. i need to load d:WorkOrder and d:Description in tableview

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Hamza Öztürk answer, Tried using XMLParse:

```
 import UIKit

 struct Book {
   var workOrder: String
   var description: String
 }

 class TableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

var books: [Book] = []
var elementName: String = String()
var bookWorkOrder = String()
var bookdescription = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Feed", withExtension: "xml") {
        if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: path) {
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
     }
   }

   // 1
   func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    if elementName == "entry" {
        bookWorkOrder = String()
        bookdescription = String()
    }

    self.elementName = elementName

    }

    // 2
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "entry" {
        let book = Book(workOrder: bookWorkOrder, description: bookdescription)
        books.append(book)
        print("count::\(books.count)")


       }
   }

   // 3
   func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if self.elementName == "d:WorkOrder" {
            bookWorkOrder += data
        } else if self.elementName == "d:Description" {
            bookdescription += data
        }
     }
   }



   // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // return the number of sections
    return 1
   }

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return the number of rows

    return books.count
   }


      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cellTableViewCell

    let book = books[indexPath.row]
    print("book::\(book.workOrder)")

    cell.workorfer.text = book.workOrder
    cell.descriptor.text = book.description


    return cell
   }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper) pod.

Using the nested mapping functionality, your model may look like this:

```
class Feed: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var entries: [Entry]?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        entries <- map["entry"]
    }
}

class Entry: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var workOrder: String?
    var description: String?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        workOrder <- map["content.m:properties.d:WorkOrder"]
        description <- map["content.m:properties.d:Description"]
    }
}
```

And you can map your XML to this model like:

```
let feed = Feed(XMLString: xmlString)
```

Or using the [Requests](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper#requests-subspec) subspec:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseXMLObject { (dataResponse: DataResponse<Feed>) in
        let feed = dataResponse.result.value
        print(feed?.toXMLString() ?? "nil")
}
```